# jqwidgets combobox color issue

Tags: html, css, combobox

[image: Color of arrow and checked items][image]

As you can see in the above picture I am just using the default combo box of jqwidgets with the jqx.base.css as the CSS file. I just can get the arrow mark on the combo and also the check boxes of the elements checked in black color.
I have tried with IE10 and Chrome 21.

Anybody out there having a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is that you did not add the images folder used by the CSS file.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I am no table to figure out what images you are talking about. Also in the hard drive location i have all the images related to jqwidgets.

Comment: Anyway moved over to Kendo UI multiselect

Comment: I meant the images in the styles/images folder of jQWidgets. The CSS files use images and in the CSS files the path points to the images sub folder. If it is not there, images will not be displayed.